# Can you programmatically submit a form in angular when it is filled?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I want to programmatically submit a form in angular when it is filled?

ts:

```
@ViewChild('f', { static: false }) public form: NgForm;
constructor(){}
public ngOnChanges(changes: any): void {}
public ngOnInit(): void {}
```

template:

```
<form class="form" #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div>
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myObj.name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
        </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think "[Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)" is the right keyword for you.

You can define your rules and add a subscription to your form with ".subscribe()"

```
myForm = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl(''),
});

constructor() {
  this.myForm.get('name').valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
    console.log('name value changed', x);
    // some magic
    this.onSubmit(); // call submit
  });
}
```